# Hibernate-search behavior?

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-search

I have an indexed entity, like below :

```
@MappedSuperclass
public static class Model{

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.Identity)
private Integer id;

private boolean isDeleted;

}
```

and the indexed class is :

```
@Entity
@Table("USERS")
@Indexed
public class ProductModel extends Model{

@Field
private String name;

//getters & setters

}
```

Well, when I do a research on `ProductModel`, I get the value of the flag `isDeleted` while its not annotated with `@Field`.

I'm asking if this is a normal behavior, does **Hibernate-search** Index the whole Object Or does it fetch the missing data from data base, I need an explanation for this behavior please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hibernate Search only stores in the index the fields you declare explicitly (more precisely, it indexes by default and you can ask Hibernate Search to store it by adding the store option to your @Field annotation).

What you observe is that Hibernate Search hydrates the objects with the information of the database after having performed the search. This is one of the main interest in using Hibernate Search: the objects returned are managed entities.

Comment: so what is the exact behavior, does it interrogate the data base for each research ??

Comment: On a typical search, yes, it runs the query against the Lucene indexes then it executes a query/queries on the database to build the managed entities. The only case where it does not do so is if you use a projection to return specific fields stored directly in the index. As I mentioned it, this is one of the nice thing of Hibernate Search.